# Capistrano, disable deployed production application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano

I have deployed my application to VPS via capistrano by using this deploy options:

```
lock '3.4.1'

set :application, 'my-production-app'
set :repo_url, 'https://path.to.my.repo/my-production-app.git'

set :linked_dirs, %w(
  bin log vendor/bundle public/system
  tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets
)

set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

# This for carrierwave
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs) + %w{public/system public/uploads}

set :pty, true

set :use_sudo, true

set :puma_bind, "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"

set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
```

Then I have `nginx.conf` file with will be working as web server:

```
upstream puma_powerwifi {
  server unix:///var/www/my-production-app/shared/tmp/sockets/my-production-app-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 8888;
  # server_name example.com;

  root /var/www/my-production-app/current/public;
  access_log /var/www/my-production-app/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /var/www/my-production-app/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

  proxy_pass http://puma_my_production;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

When I deploy my application to my server, it works fine. Now I want to turn it off and I don't know how.

How to SAFELY disable rails production application which was deployed via capistrano?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stopping the Puma server will disable the app.

You can do it with `bundle exec cap production puma:stop` from your deployment (local) machine.

Start it again with `bundle exec cap production puma:start`.

This assumes you are using the `capistrano-puma` gem, which looks like you are based on your posted config. Note that this only disables the Rails app, and your VPS and Nginx keep running.